# How can I cut out certain parts of text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is the logo I have in mind:

[image]

I have been using white rectangles as blocs to hide the words like this:

[image]

However, when I merge the layers of text and white rectangles together, I am seeing something like this when I turn my background transparent:

[image]

It's very time consuming and laborous to manually delete those white spots in the final layer. If I change the color of the white rectangles to transparent then I am not seeing any "cutting" of the letters because it's transparent!!

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Type out your text.

Make sure the type layer is selected and add a layer mask. You can find this in the layers panel (Window -> Layers if you don't see it). Select the square icon with the circle cutout in the middle.

[image: add a layer mask]

Now use whatever tool you want to make a selection for the parts you want to hide.

I suggest using the pen tool (P) however you can use whichever selection tool you're used to using.

[image: Pen tool selection]

**(If using the pen tool)** Right click on the selection -> Make selection. Press OK on the next screen.

Now fill the selection with black using the brush tool (B) or fill tool (G).

Result

[image: The result]

Comment: It doesn't really work on transparent backgrounds because once I save it for web I am getting white areas for the cut out  parts

Comment: I am using a layer mask. The parts I paint with black will hide that part of the layer. There is no "white areas" in my method. I am confused when you're using white if doing my method. Remember I am using a layer mask not a clipping mask.

Comment: @Sparrowcide, I will go out on a limb and ask, when you save for web are you using a format that supports transparency like PNG-24 or GIF? What is transparent in Photoshop should save as such in these formats.

Answer (score 0):

use a mask, you'd still have to do it manually, just means you can alter it afterwards of you wont like it, plus nothing white to hide

[image]

Comment: I am trying to see how you were able to reverse the clipping masks. I am only able to do it the other way... http://imgur.com/a/9UDw5

Comment: @Sparrowcide You invert Layer mask the same way you invert colors in a normal image. Just click the Layer mask thumbnail to select it and `Image > Adjustments > Invert`. Although you can initially create the mask that way by clicking the Layer mask icon while holding down `Alt`.

Comment: @Sparrowcide your screenshot of clipping masks doesn't even look like Photoshop, that looks like Illustrator. Which are you using? Pal_man and Joonas are explaining using Layer Masks, not Clipping Masks.