# Photoshop: How can I delete a part of a charcacter converted into work path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

I have the below situation and I am trying to remove the right part of this character (background color + working path).

What I've tried:

- [Layer mask](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62133/how-can-i-cut-out-certain-parts-of-text) but not so happy with the result when we have another visible element over the masked area, there are some visible thin strokes; Please find the exported pdf result.[image]
- Using the delete anchor point tool, I've managed to redefine a specified zone but I can't loose the background color. Actually I thought that this will be enough to have a new shape but not. In the same time, I can't use the erase tool because first I should rasterize and I don't want that.

[image]

- Using the direct select tool (A) selecting the right unwanted area + deleting but I came back to the previous phase, being unable to delete the color that fill that path, or at least I don't know how to do it without rasterize the layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to use a vector image editor for creating or editing vectors, either Adobe Illustrator or even the free software Inkscape.org - Photoshop on the other hand only has very basic vector capabilities.

In any case, it can be done in Photoshop.

1. Add anchor points using the Add Anchor Point tool, where you want to cut it
2. Use the Direct Selection tool A to click drag a selection box around the anchors you want to delete.
3. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>
4. Change the shape fill to `No Color` - or choose a different colour fill.

[image: Illustrated Steps to Cut a Shape and Change Fill]

Comment: It looks so easy, I'll try that; I guess that the step 4 is what I am looking for, this is where the magic happens :) Thank you,

Comment: LE: this is Photoshop or Illustrator? in step 3 when you pressed delete the left path is gone including the background color? actually the step 3 is what I am looking for.

Comment: The steps are for Photoshop, since that's what you asked for. Yes when you press delete you delete the anchors, path and fill in that region

Comment: All good :) note: the layer text should be converted in Shape not working path that's why I had the described issues. Thanks once again,